# Measurement of cross section

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, scattering-cross-section

When we measure the [cross section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_%28physics%29) of an interaction what is it that we actually measure in a real experiment?

I know what cross section is and how to derive an expression for a given process but I have no idea how we go about actually measuring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically measure the probability of the event. For example, you shoot X-rays at a known blob of material and measure the fraction of Xryas that were deflected / absorbed. You can then imagine each atom in the material to have a certain cross section, and imagine whether you could "shoot past" all those atoms for a given average cross section.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was so immersed in the derivation of the cross section through the invariant matrix element that I completely forgot that the simple formula for cross section is rate/incident flux.